# For-Else loop in another For loop

Tags: python, algorithm, program-structure, for-else

I have some question regarding the for-else loop in another for loop. So here is an example:

```
primelist = []
for p in range (2, x+1):
    print 'in first for'
    raw_input()
    for i in range(2, p):
        print 'in second for'
        if p%i == 0:
            print 'in if'
            raw_input()
            break
    else:
        print 'in else'
        raw_input()
        primelist = primelist + [p]
return primelist
```

As you see this is for determining the prime numbers and store them into a list so that they can be retrieved later. So my problem is with the first for loop. When I run the program, it enters like this: First FOR loop, ELSE, First FOR loop, Second FOR loop and so on. Why does it skip to ELSE the first time?
Also if I ask for the 1000th number I get : 7919 with the

```
for i in range(2, p)
```

and 7907 with the

```
for i in range(2, p/2).
```

Why is that? 
Hope you will help me with this, but please do not give other methods for implementing the Prime Number algorithm!

Comment: As you've written it, this code has a syntax error. Did you mean to indent the `else` statement (and its children) to be inline with the `if` statement?

Comment: @Hooked You can `else` a `for` in Python.  The condition gets entered if the loop terminates without `break`ing.

Comment: @SilasRay wow, I didn't realize that. My mistake BlackTM. I'll leave my comment up for others to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `range` doesn't include the ending value.

```
range[start, end)
```

So, In the first iteration, value of `p` will be 2 and `range(2, 2)` is an empty list. That is why the else part is entered.

```
print range(2, 2)  # []
```